# Inbound Windows Firewall Core Networking Rules

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ipv6, windows-firewall

I've just purchase a Windows Server 2008 R2 VPS plan and I was alarmed to see the default configuration had Windows firewall disabled. I've enabled the firewall and disabled most of the inbound rules, but I have some uncertainty about the rules in the Core Networking category. I know that I don't want DHCP in, so I've disabled both the IP4 and IP6 versions, but I'm at a loss for the other entries in this category:

```
IGMP
IPHTTPS
IPv6
Multicast Listener Done, Query, Report and Report v2
Neighbor Discovery Advertisement and Solicitation
Packet Too Big
Parameter Problem
Router Advertisement
Router Solicitation
Teredo
Time Exceeded
```

The only planned inbound connections for this server are HTTP, HTTPS, and RDP, so my preference is to disable all of these rules. However, I want to make sure this isn't going to cause any unexpected problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You absolutely should leave these on ...

- Packet Too Big
- Parameter Problem
- Time Exceeded

You absolutely should leave these on if you are going do be doing any IPv6

- IPv6
- Multicast Listener Done, Query, Report and Report v2
- Neighbor Discovery Advertisement and Solicitation
- Router Advertisement
- Router Solicitation

And I would disable these ...

- IPHTTPS
- Teredo
- IGMP (unless your doing IPv4 multicasting)

Comment: I have some time to explain my answer ...  "Packet Too Big" is required for PMTUD and if you drop this packet a small number of your users, particularly if they connect via vpn's or tunnels, may not be able to connect to your site.

Answer (score 1):

You're good in blocking the others as they are mainly internetworking protocols with other networking equipment.